# Headset Buzzing when laptop power plugged in

Tags: usb, audio, thinkpad, microphone, noise

I have a Thinkpad Edge E535 Laptop and a Logitech G35 headet. When I use the microphone to record stuff there is a small humming/buzzing sound in the background when the laptop is plugged in to AC. There is no grounding on the power cord at all and the headset is usb.

Link to audio file http://dropcanvas.com/72gc6

Comment: To me this happens with the speakers when the wifi is on (sometimes). You may have some interference.